# Targeting a new tab in Selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver

I have a test which essentially will click a link on the footer of the page. We have three of them and they all lead to different places:

- A Google Docs form
- A training page
- A licensing page

The code below makes the right assertions and clicks the link:

```
if @link_selection.eql?('leave feedback')
    @wait.until {@driver.find_element(css: => 'cell.feedback').click}
    @wait.until {@driver.find_element(css: => 'a[href="https://docs.google.com/a/showmyhomework.co.uk/forms/d/1LP8BZ950TSXXDR1HuVz7yhv9Cp3h6scmQtNFqIRW_XI/viewform"').click}
    puts "Leave feedback link clicked"
```

I've modularised it for each different link location. 
When the link is clicked, it naturally opens in a new browser tab. I then wanted to extend the test to then view the tab which was opened and then make an assertion on that page. I wanted to ask how I can handle a new tab in Selenium and the way in that:

a. It asserts that the new tab is open (and switches to it)
b. It can then assert a heading or title of the page (so that the test is sure that the page has been opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code in c#, please feel free to change it to ruby.

```
// This gets the window handles of open available windows(also, tabs)
var availableWindows= driver.WindowHandles;
```

To switch to the new tab with respect to the title of the page:

```
 string Title= "whateveryourpagetitleis";
    foreach (string windowId in availableWindows)
                {
                    string windowTitle = driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowId).Title;
                    if (windowTitle.ContainsIgnoreCase(title))
                    {
                        driver.SwitchTo().Window(windowId);
                    }
                }
```

You can play around with the functions and then use your asserts accordingly. But, what you're looking for is `WindowHandles`